# Port forwarding to Raspberry Pi web server not working

Tags: linux, router, apache-http-server, port-forwarding, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to set up a local web server on the raspberry pi but I can't get port forwarding set up so I can access it outside my local network. I have a Verizon router, and I've set up port forwarding on port 443 to the local IP of the pi. Here is a screenshot of that port forwarding table :

[image]

I have Apache set up on the pi to listen on ports 80 and 443. Here's the output of `netstat -lptn` :

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

Still, when I go to `https://{my-ip}` from a cellular connection (not on my WiFi) I can't connect to the server. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: According to your netstat output it looks to me like Apache is not listening on port 80 for regular TCP/IP  (it appears to be only listening for port 80 on ipv6 - not ipv4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure this out. It came from the fact that I have Google Nest wifi, so I had to forward requests from my ISP router to that, then from that to the raspberry pi. Seems obvious in hindsight, but I forgot about it earlier.